# Nextjs dynamic route raises 500 Internal server error, on page reload on production Only

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, deployment, netlify

I have a simple nextjs latest version app, everything works as expected.

Except in the detail page in [id] folder, raises 500 Internal server error, **Only** in manual page **reload** and **Only** on **production** (i use netlify and firebase).

in the main page :

```
    async function getData() {
     const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/...')
     return res.json()
     }
     
    export default async function Page() {
    const posts = await getData()
          return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li key={post.id}>
          <Link href={`/blog/${post.id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
```

then in [id]/page.js:

a page with just a function displaying hello, (just for testing)

```
 <p>Hello</p>
```

has anyone got in the same situation, or have insights on this? thank you.

***Kind of a Solution:***

It appears that this problem happend only in **nextjs** deployed to **Netlify**.

I re-deployed the same app to **Vercel** and it is not showing the any sign of that behaviour and all works as expected.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. it works fine in dev but not production on netlify

Comment: I deployed it on vercel and it works, i still don't know the cause of it with Netlify